# EF Core Include() gives null after query

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql, entity-framework, .net-6.0

I have a project that is running with .net core 6, EF Core 6.0.9, DB -> postgresql 14.

I have these classes

```cs
    public class Language
    {
        [Key]
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string PublicId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Course> CoursesFrom { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Course> CoursesTo { get; set; }
    }

    public class Course
    {
        [Key]
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string PublicId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual Language LanguageFrom { get; set; }
        public virtual Language LanguageTo { get; set; }
    }
```

The relation is defined as follows:

```cs
    public class LanguageConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Language>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Language> builder)
        {
            ...
            builder.HasMany(l => l.CoursesFrom)
                   .WithOne(c => c.LanguageFrom);

            builder.HasMany(l => l.CoursesTo)
                   .WithOne(c => c.LanguageTo);
        }
    }
```

```cs
    public class CourseConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Course>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Course> builder)
        {
            ...
            builder.HasOne(l => l.LanguageFrom)
                   .WithMany(c => c.CoursesFrom)
                   .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);

            builder.HasOne(l => l.LanguageTo)
                   .WithMany(c => c.CoursesTo)
                   .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
        }
    }
```

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new LanguageConfiguration());
    modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new CourseConfiguration());
}
```

And LINQ expression

```cs
var query = Context.Course
                .Include(l => l.LanguageFrom)
                .Include(l => l.LanguageTo)
                .ToList();
```

Main entity is returned but fields LanguageFrom and LanguageTo are null - the Include() does nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked if the data is present in the database? Have you checked  the generated SQL?

Comment: Database is populated with data, tbh I haven't checked the SQL but I managed to solve this problem by adding AutoInclude in the CourseConfiguration to LanguageFrom and LanguageTo properties :) Thx everyone for help :)

Answer (score 0):

When there are multiple navigation properties defined between two types [shadow navigation properties do not work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key). You should define two fields to serve as foreign key in the Course entity:

```
public class Course
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string PublicId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long LanguageFromId { get; set; }
    public long LanguageToId { get; set; }

    public virtual Language LanguageFrom { get; set; }
    public virtual Language LanguageTo { get; set; }
}
```

Then

```
public class CourseConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Course>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Course> builder)
    {
        ...
        builder.HasOne(l => l.LanguageFrom)
               .WithMany(c => c.CoursesFrom)
               .HasForeignKey("LanguageFromId")
               .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);

        builder.HasOne(l => l.LanguageTo)
               .WithMany(c => c.CoursesTo)
               .HasForeignKey("LanguageToId")
               .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately same result :(